# Java unlock ReadWrite lock safely?

Tags: java, locking

I have a write lock object which I need to unlock, but I am not sure that it is locked (it depends on same variables). Calling unlock will throw exception if it is not locked. What I am currently doing is this:

```
if (fWriteLock.tryLock())
            fWriteLock.unlock();
```

Isn't there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clearer way would be `if(fWriteLock.isHeldByCurrentThread())`, but if you don't know whether you have the lock or not, it sounds like you may have design issues.

Comment: Nice, i didn't see this method since I've looked at Lock's interface and not ReentrantReadWriteLock.